# $_GET color variables

Tags: php, colors, get

I am trying to display $_GET variables from a URL that are colors and have a number sign (hash) in them (*aka, say "#ff0000" for red*), but I can't seem to get it to work. *I can't change the colors output to anything other than color hex codes (out of my control), so that's not a solution.*

Here is the problem currently:

```
// URL: http://__________.com/styles.php?color=#f6f6f6&color2=#fff
var_dump($_GET['color']);
// Returns string(0) ""
```

The usage on the page referencing it is:

`<link href='//__________.com/styles.php?color={color}&color2={color2}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

So when the page loads it outputs the URL from the first code snippet (`http://__________.com/styles.php?color=#f6f6f6&color2=#fff`).

Additionally, what's the best way to filter_input if the variable exists or not. For example, I was using this, but I don't think it's correct:

`$color = ($_GET['color'] != '' ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'color', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED) : 'green');`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At address bar the sign # has different meaning.

You should use urlencode()

```
urlencode("http://__________.com/styles.php?color=#f6f6f6&color2=#fff")
```

and from the other side `urldecode`

With that said, here is an example:
If i want to pass the hash-tag `#` i will need to replace it with another matching string, ie: `%23` that is the matching string for hash-tag.

So my string will be like this:

```
http://__________.com/styles.php?color=%23f6f6f6&color2=%23fff
```

At PHP side i will decode the given value.

```
$myColor = urldecode($_GET['color]);
```

And it will now save the color i intended `#f6f6f6`

Comment: Would it be a problem though if the side referencing `http://______.com/styles.php?color=#f6f6f6&color2=#fff` doesn't have php or anything like? I don't think I can use `urlencode` then?

Comment: If you see my addition though, it's being used in a stylesheet reference, so how does that change your answer?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the # is a reserved URL character. See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)
When generating the URL, encode it so that the # is URL-safe.

To encode, simply replace all ocurrences of # with %23